# How to select a layer in Photoshop by clicking on layer content?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I know I can ctrl-click on content, but this will select parent / the top of all layers which is really frustrating. If I click on layer's content I want my layer to be selected even though it is nested in multiple layers... I hope I make sense?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Photoshop has 2 types of selecting methods. This option is shown at the top when you have the Move Tool (V) selected.

[image: auto select options]

Auto Checked - Will select the top most layer content when selecting objects on the artboard.

Unchecked - Will select the layer content for which layer you have selected in the layers panel.

Comment: ohh... if only i asked sooner! it would save me a lot of frustration..